# adding multiple records into local storage

Tags: javascript, json, html

what I'm trying to do is to add multiple values(user1,user2,user3...) into a local storage using html5. But the problem is that whenever I add a record, the old record is deleted.this is my code if anyone can help please:

```
         $("#submit").click(function(){
         if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
        try {
            var user = JSON.stringify({ 
                 email : $("#email").val(), 
                 username : $("#username").val(), 
                 password : $("#password").val(), 
                    });

            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user)); 
            alert("The data was saved."); 
            return true;
        } catch (e) {
            if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
                alert('Quota exceeded!');
            }
        }
        } else {
            alert('Cannot store user preferences as your browser do not support local storage');
        }
    });
```

please anyone can help???

Comment: local storage is dictionary based storage, we can have one value with reference to one key.

Comment: what you want to do is create a local database, the required job can be done using indexed DB. refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB

Answer (score 2):

You could use email to identify each record (email being unique):

```
var user = {
    email : $("#email").val(), 
    username : $("#username").val(), 
    password : $("#password").val()
}

var record = JSON.stringify(user);
localStorage.setItem(user.email, record);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
## This would be a simple way to save multiple data into localStorage ##    


var arrList=[];
var dataList=null;
var dataValue={email : $("#email").val(), 
             username : $("#username").val(), 
             password : $("#password").val()};
dataList=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localKey"));

if(arrList!=null)
{
arrList=dataList;
arrList.push(dataValue);

}
 else{

arrList.push(dataValue);
}
localStorage.setItem("localKey",JSON.stringify(arrList);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `localStorage` in a browser is just a simple key-value store. Either give each user their own key or make the `user` key an Array of users.

Comment: Yes. `JSON.stringify([{ ... }, { ... }, { ... }])` works just fine.

Comment: im sorry i wasn't clear what i want is whenever i add a record a new key user1,user2,user3... to be created with value of that record and the value is a json object

Comment: You'll have to keep track of a global variable, which you could keep in localStorage as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can store an array of users. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/7sqXg/).

```
var user = JSON.stringify({ 
                 email : $("#email").val(), 
                 username : $("#username").val(), 
                 password : $("#password").val(), 
                    }),
                users = localStorage.getItem('user');

            users = users ? JSON.parse(users) : [];

            users.push(user);

            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(users));
```

Comment: this do work but doesn't create a new key every time a record is entered.i want a new user to be created which contain the json object

Comment: @user3789242 OIC. But you can use index as an id. `JSON.parse(localStorage.user)[0]` or whatever index you need.